# Unable to create aws-auth config map in EKS using Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create an `aws-auth` ConfigMap in EKS (v1.24) using Terraform (v1.0.3) and get an error:

Here is my TF code:

```
locals {
  aws_auth_cm = <<-EOT
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  data:
    mapAccounts: '123456'
    mapRoles: |-
      - groups:
        - system:masters
        rolearn: arn:aws:iam::123456:role/Admin_11223344
        username: Admin_11223344
      - groups:
        - system:masters
        rolearn: arn:aws:iam::123456:role/bla_44332211
        username: bla_44332211
    mapUsers: |-
      - groups:
        - system:masters
        userarn: arn:aws:iam::123456:user/aabbccdd
        username: aabbccdd
    EOT
}

resource "null_resource" "patch_aws_auth" {
  triggers = {
    aws_auth_cm = local.aws_auth_cm
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command     = <<EOT
    aws eks --region ${var.region} update-kubeconfig --name ${var.cluster_name} --kubeconfig ~/.kube/${var.region}-${var.cluster_name}
    KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/${var.region}-${var.cluster_name} kubectl patch aws_auth_cm aws-auth --patch "${local.aws_auth_cm}" -n kube-system
    EOT
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error from server: admission webhook "eks-aws-auth-configmap-validation-webhook.amazonaws.com" denied the request: 
Found Invalid YAML format in either mapRoles, mapUsers or mapAccounts. Please check for proper yaml format and try again.
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `mapAccounts` value to a list rather than just a plain string?